# Using derived column for trailing zeros

Tags: ssis

I Have a column IN a  SQL table that has these values(`'NONE','3.00','3.50'`). When I export into comma delimited file USING SQL Server integration services I lose my trialing Zeros. I need the values AS is.

Answer (score 0):

In the connection manager for the output file, make sure you have the column meta data set to either of the two STRING data types and then add the double quotes as a text qualifier.

Comment: I only want one column not all column. when i add double quotes in the flat file connection  manager / general page. the double quote is added to all columns

Comment: What are you doing with the CSV file once the data is outputted?